# Multiple Retrofit calls with Flow

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I made app where user can add server (recycler row) to favorites. It only saves the IP and Port. Than, when user open `FavoriteFragment` Retrofit makes calls for each server

```
 @GET("v0/server/{ip}/{port}")
    suspend fun getServer(
        @Path("ip") ip: String,
        @Path("port") port: Int
    ): Server
```

So in `repository` I mix the sources and make multiple calls:

```
suspend fun getFavoriteServersToRecyclerView(): Flow<DataState<List<Server>>> = flow {
        emit(DataState.Loading)
        try {
            val getFavoritesServersNotLiveData = favoritesDao.getFavoritesServersNotLiveData()
            val list: MutableList<Server> = mutableListOf()
            getFavoritesServersNotLiveData.forEach { fav ->
                val server = soldatApiService.getServer(fav.ip, fav.port)
                list.add(server)
            }
            emit(DataState.Success(list))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(DataState.Error(e))
        }
    }
```

and then in `ViewModel` I create `LiveData` object

```
fun getFavoriteServers() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getFavoriteServersToRecyclerView()
                .onEach { dataState ->
                    _favoriteServers.value = dataState
                }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
        }
    }
```

And everything works fine till the Favorite server is not more available in the Lobby and the Retrofit call failure.
My question is: how to skip the failed call in the loop without crashing whole function.

Answer (score 0):

Emit another flow in catch with `emitAll` if you wish to continue flow like onResumeNext with RxJava

```
   catch { cause ->
      emitAll(flow { emit(DataState.Errorcause)})
   }
```

Comment: How to continue with coroutines?

Comment: When you emit with this on catch it continues that coroutines with emitted data

Comment: I'm working on a sample with chained coroutines but not finished yet but coroutines work, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/CoroutinesAndFlowTutorials/blob/master/Tutorial2-1FlowBasics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial2_1flowbasics/chapter4_single_source_of_truth/domain/GetPostsUseCase.kt)

Comment: I dont understeand this example, Maybe better idea would be use old RetrofitCallback?

Comment: When you use emitAll inside a catch block it let's you continue the flow with the emitted data.

Comment: I tried `catch (e: Exception) { emitAll(flow { emit(DataState.Error(e)) }) }` and still get 404

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution:

```
 suspend fun getFavoriteServersToRecyclerView(): Flow<DataState<List<Server>>> = flow {
        emit(DataState.Loading)

        val list: MutableList<Server> = mutableListOf()

        try {
            val getFavoritesServersNotLiveData = favoritesDao.getFavoritesServersNotLiveData()

            val job = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch {
                getFavoritesServersNotLiveData.forEach { fav ->
                    val server = getServer(fav.ip, fav.port)

                    server.collect { dataState ->
                        when (dataState) {
                            is DataState.Loading -> Log.d(TAG, "loading")
                            is DataState.Error -> Log.d(TAG, dataState.exception.message!!)
                            is DataState.Success -> {
                                list.add(dataState.data)
                                Log.d(TAG, dataState.data.toString())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            job.join()
            emit(DataState.Success(list))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(DataState.Error(e))
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is "DataState" ?

Answer (score 0):

when using retrofit you can wrap response object with `Response<T>` *(import response from retrofit)* so that,

```
@GET("v0/server/{ip}/{port}")
    suspend fun getServer(
        @Path("ip") ip: String,
        @Path("port") port: Int
    ): Response<Server>
```

and then in the Repository you can check if network failed without using **try-catch**

```
suspend fun getFavoriteServersToRecyclerView(): Flow<DataState<List<Server>>> = flow {
        emit(DataState.Loading)
        val getFavoritesServersNotLiveData = favoritesDao.getFavoritesServersNotLiveData()
        if(getFavoritesServersNotLiveData.isSuccessful) {
            
            val list: MutableList<Server> = mutableListOf()
            getFavoritesServersNotLiveData.body().forEach { fav ->
                val server = soldatApiService.getServer(fav.ip, fav.port)
                // if the above request fails it wont go to the else block
                list.add(server)
            }
            emit(DataState.Success(list))
        } else {
            val error = getFavoritesServersNotLiveData.errorBody()!!
            //do something with error
        }
    }
```